# Type "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I want to set a default value for a BOOLEAN type:

```java
@Column(nullable = false, name = "is_activated", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE")
private Boolean isActivated = false;
```

However, running the server will throw

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE" does not exist
  Position: 121
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted.jar:9.4.1208]
```

and I don't get why because other examples I saw do just that.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Can you try `@Column(name = "is_activated", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE")`, i.e. remove `nullable` and include it in the `columnDefinition`? (This is just a guess...)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Nope, this will give me the same error unfortunately: `ERROR: type "BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE" does not exist`

Comment: If I am reading the specs right, it should be possible. Could it be a bug of Hibernate+Postgres dialect? What version are you using?

Comment: Why not post the actual DDL issued by your JPA provider?

Comment: I started getting such error after setting this property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the `globally_quoted_identifiers` configuration enabled and it is generating a SQL script with `columnDefinition` between quotes which is invalid:

```
alter table if exists "my_table" add column "is_activated" "BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE";
```

If so, then you will need to enable `globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions` so that it generates a valid SQL script with `columnDefinition` unquoted:

```
alter table if exists "my_table" add column "is_activated" BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Please check your application configuration to see if this is the case.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
```